# Populate a numbered row until reaching a specific value with another column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table full of account numbers and period/terms for  loan(loan term is in months)

What I need to do is populate a numbered row for each account number that is less than or equal to the loan term. I've attached a screen shot below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcn7n.png)

So for this specific example, I will need 48 numbered rows for this account number, as the term is only 48 months.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your database version? (Such as 12.1.0.2.0) If you don't know for sure, `select * from v$version`. Different answers are available in different versions of the database.

Comment: Please post formatted text [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Oracle version: 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

```
with
     test_data ( account_nmbr, term ) as (
       select 'ABC200', 6 from dual union all
       select 'DEF100', 8 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select     level as row_nmbr, term, account_nmbr
from       test_data
connect by level <= term
       and prior account_nmbr = account_nmbr
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by   account_nmbr, row_nmbr   --   If needed
;

  ROW_NMBR        TERM  ACCOUNT_NMBR
  --------  ----------  ------------
         1           6  ABC200
         2           6  ABC200
         3           6  ABC200
         4           6  ABC200
         5           6  ABC200
         6           6  ABC200
         1           8  DEF100
         2           8  DEF100
         3           8  DEF100
         4           8  DEF100
         5           8  DEF100
         6           8  DEF100
         7           8  DEF100
         8           8  DEF100
```

In Oracle 12, you can use the `LATERAL` clause for the same:

```
with
     test_data ( account_nmbr, term ) as (
       select 'ABC200', 6 from dual union all
       select 'DEF100', 8 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   l.row_nmbr, t.term, t.account_nmbr
from     test_data t,
         lateral (select level as row_nmbr from dual connect by level <= term) l
order by account_nmbr, row_nmbr   --  If needed
;
```

Comment: The second query worked perfectly in 11g. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @DieHard345 - do you mean the **first** query worked in 11g? If the second query actually did work, that would be very surprising, since `LATERAL` was introduced (or at least documented) only in Oracle 12.1.

Comment: The lateral query worked in the 11g database I'm running this off of. I even ran select * from v$version to confirm the version. Thanks again for the help.